# Kotlin force override of a function

Tags: kotlin

I'm creating a base class.
I have **start()** with some **code**.
And a **bar()** that needs to be overidden by a class that inherits **Foo**

**start() calls bar()**

My example (foo.kt) :

```
open class Foo {
    fun start() {
        bar()
        //...
    }
    fun bar() {
        TODO("implement me in deriving class")
    }
}
```

I don't like **bar()** throwing an **exception**
I don't like leaving **bar()** with **blank body** either

Is there something I forgot that is a **better alternative** in Kotlin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make your method (and consequently, your class) [`abstract`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#abstract-classes):

```
abstract class Foo {
    fun start() {
        bar()
        //...
    }
    abstract bar()
}
```

This will force any non-abstract class that inherits from `Foo` to implement the `bar` method, as well as prevent anyone from creating an instance of the base `Foo` class directly.

Comment: I can do that in Java, not in Kotlin right? start() contains some code

Comment: You can do it in both, abstract classes work the same way in both languages.

Comment: Abstract is correct, I still have some issues in my real code but it's another problem.

Comment: Any idea how to achieve this without making it abstract? For example, I have a method in super, which I want child to override, but leaving the implementation in super.

Comment: In that case, your method that contains some implementation could call into another abstract function in the base class, which the child would have to override.